# How to play .dvs (DTI's DVSSDiscPlayer format) on Linux systems?

Tags: audio, video, conversion, database

*.dvs* is the exotic extension of a file / a database of files / a database of streams (cross out wrong). This type of file is used in the CCTV to let the operator watch the recording from, let's say, three cameras, a GPS and a microphone. Imagine a bus with the CCTV system combined out of three cameras, a microphone and a GPS plotter. A supervisor, a judge or a police officer would like to check what happened in a given moment at time. The *.dvs* format enables him to watch everything in one place *i.e.* in the GUI of the *DVSSDiscPlayer.exe* – a portable software made by the *Digital Technology International*, working under Windows systems. The effect is similar to the merger of the streams in *ffmpeg* or *oggmerge*, however, the streams are separate, only kept in sync.

1. Is it possible to play the *.dvs* file on Linux-es? (*How?*)
2. Is it possible to convert a *.dvs* file into something watch-/hear-able on Linux?
3. How to extract the soundtrack from the *.dvs* file?
4. Is it possible to extract the soundtrack into a format that can be:

   - amplified
   - noise-reduced
   - or convertible into such a format?

Comment: If you can do #2 then all the other options are straight-forward. If there is any text in a header etc, the `strings` command can print any likely text data.